# How can a stored proc retrieve the name of the database it's running in?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which can be run in a number of databases, and the functioning of the stored procedure needs to vary slightly depending on the database.  I've been all over books online and looked in the system tables to see if this might be somewhere in there, but so far no joy.

There's got to be someone here who just happens to know this, if it exists at all.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but would'nt you already know that based on your database connection properties?

Comment: No such thing as a dumb question, they say.  But the db connection properties is found in the code accessing the database, and isn't available to the stored procedure.  I'm working with some legacy code that does not pass this info to the SP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT db_name()
```

Should do it.  Docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A procedure always runs in the database it exists in. Invoking `EXEC <dbfoo>..<procname>` is exactly as swithing context to `<dbfoo>` then executing `<procname>`.

If you have multiple procedures, one in each DB, then you can either change the procedure accordingly on each DB or use [DB_NAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx) to get the current db.